# Javascript validation for more than one field

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I currently have this code:

```
:javascript
  function showstuff(alert){
     document.getElementById(alert).style.display="inline";
  }



:javascript

  function validateForm()
  {

  var x=document.forms["form"]["name"].value;
  if (x==null || x=="")
    {


    showstuff('alert');
    return false;
    }
  }


.alert.alert-danger{:id => "alert", :style => "display:none"} 
  %strong Error 
  \- Please make sure you fill out all the required fields!
```

Which works fine for one field, but is there a simple way of making it work for 4 different fields rather than copying and pasting the code four times?

Comment: So why not put OR in your if statement for all the fields you need validation

Comment: You can put the field names in an array and run your validation in a loop

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the fields of your form

```
var field, x;


for(var i in document.forms['form'])
{ 
  if(document.forms['form'].hasOwnProperty(i))
  {
      field = document.forms['form'][i];
      x = field.value;
      // Do your validation here for that field
  }
}
```

Or, if you want to specify the fields you wish to validate

```
function validateForm(fields)
{
     var x;
     for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
     {
         x=document.forms["form"][fields[i]].value;
         if (x==null || x=="")
         {
           showstuff('alert');
           return false;
         }
     }
}

validateForm(['name', 'name_of_other_field']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function validateForm()
  {
      var valid = true;
      var fieldNames = ["name", "age", "city"];
      for(var i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++){
          valid = (validateField(fieldNames[i]) && valid) ? true:false;
      }
  }

  function validateField(fieldName){
     if (!document.forms["form"][fieldName].value)
     {
         return showstuff('alert');
     }
  }
```

Comment: Didn't make a difference I'm afraid!